# How to edit a line programmatically in the database using formset?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

I wish I could instantiate my fields answer when there is one and instead it adds a this changes the value directly in the database but with my formset I can 't I do not know how to change a value ...

My models.py :

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Question(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    page = models.ManyToManyField(Page)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.label

class Reply(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Personne)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.answer)
```

and my views.py :

```
def access(request, instance):
    questions = Question.objects.filter(page=instance)
    replies = Reply.objects.filter(question=instance)
    pages = Page.objects.all()
    numPages = Page.objects.get(pk=instance)
    length_questions = len(questions)
    logged_user = get_logged_user_from_request(request)
    instance = {'instance':instance}
    ReplyFormSet = modelformset_factory(model=Reply, form=ReplyForm, extra=length_questions)
    ReplyFormSet.form = staticmethod(curry(ReplyForm, instance=numPages))
    if logged_user:
        if request.method == 'POST':  
            formset = ReplyFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if formset.is_valid():
                new_instances = formset.save(commit=False)
                for new_instance in new_instances:
                    new_instance.user = logged_user
                    new_instance.save()
                return render_to_response('polls/access.html', {
         'formset': formset,
         'questions':questions,
         'logged_user':logged_user,
         'numPages' : numPages
         })
            else:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "L'ajout à bien été effectué !")
                return render_to_response('polls/access.html', {
         'formset': formset,
         'questions':questions,
         'logged_user':logged_user,
         'numPages' : numPages
         })
        else:
            formset = ReplyFormSet(queryset = Reply.objects.none())
        return render_to_response('polls/access.html', {
         'formset': formset,
         'questions':questions,
         'logged_user':logged_user,
         'numPages' : numPages
         })
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

and my template :

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {{ formset.management_form }} {% csrf_token %}
    <table>

      <br>{{ formset.as_table }}<br>

 </table><br>
    <center><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
    <a href="../../baseVisite/" class="btn btn-success">Retour</a></center>
  </form>
```

**I want to know how to instantiate my form to edit a line in my database. That is to say if I have already answered a question and I want to change the answer How can I make her my formset?**

I can not instantiate this line : `formset = ReplyFormSet(queryset = Reply.objects.none(), instance=replies)`

I get this error : `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'`

```
Traceback:

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/webtrial/polls/views.py" in access
  403.              q_form = QuestionForm(instance=question, prefix='q_'+str(question.id)+'_')

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __init__
  562.         super(BaseModelFormSet, self).__init__(**defaults)

Exception Type: TypeError at /access/1/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'
```

Comment: Please explain your problem properly. The only text in your question is impossible to understand. Please say what result you expect, what you get instead, and any errors you see.

Comment: What I have understood from your question (plus your previous almost similar questions), you want to display a list of question belonging to current page along with their answers, where users can add a new answer for a question or delete previous one. Am I right?

Comment: @ Muhammad Tair yes you have understand I want to add or change an answer

Answer (score 1):

You are creating only one `ReplyFormset` for all of your questions. You need a separate `form` for each question and a separate `formset` of each question's replies. I have not tested it yet, but I think this should work for you.

forms.py

```
QuestionForm = modelform_factory(Question)
ReplyInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Question, Reply, extra=1)
```

views.py

```
def access(request, page_id):
    page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_id)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(page=page)
    forms = list()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for question in questions:
            q_form = QuestionForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=question, prefix='q_'+str(question.id)+'_')
            r_formset = ReplyInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=question, prefix=q_form.prefix)
            forms.append((q_form, r_formset))
        if all(q_form.is_valid() and r_formset.is_valid() for q_form, r_formset in forms):
            for q_form, r_formset in forms:
                q_form.save()
                r_formset.save()
    else:
        for question in questions:
            q_form = QuestionForm(instance=question, prefix='q_'+str(question.id)+'_')
            r_formset = ReplyInlineFormSet(instance=question, prefix=q_form.prefix)
            forms.append((q_form, r_formset))
    return render_to_response('polls/access.html', {
        'forms': forms,
    })
```

template.html

```
<form method="POST" action="">
{% for form, formset in forms %}
    {{ form }}
    {{ formset }}
{% endfor%}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```

The main idea here is to separate `form` and `formsets` for each question using `prefix` parameter when creating forms and formsets so that Django's internal mechanism may differentiate between different `forms` and `formsets`.

**Edit:**
According to your traceback, you are declaring `ReplyInlineFormSet` like

```
ReplyInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Question, Reply, extra=1, fields=('Question', 'answer'))
```

In `inlineformset_factory` `fields` attribute holds fields for model (here `Reply`) and you are passing `'Question'` as a field which `Reply` model does not have. So you need to do

```
ReplyInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Question, Reply, extra=1, fields=('answer', ))
```

Comment: I get this error : `Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`

Comment: I have edited the answer. Error was in this line `prefix='q_'+question.id+'_'`. Replaced it with `prefix='q_'+str(question.id)+'_'`

Comment: I get the same error that initially my code `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'`

Comment: @JeremyLgdr please past complete stack trace of the error.

Comment: @JeremyLgdr yes, you edited my answer to put traceback, see my edit.

Comment: Yes I settle this problem, look at my last traceback is not the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104424/discussion-between-muhammad-tahir-and-jeremy-lgdr).